# Keep same scale in different graphs ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create 3 graphs in ggplot2 as follows:

```
ggplot(observbest,aes(x=factor(iteration),y=bottles,colour=Team ,group=Team)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(16)) 
ggplot(observmedium,aes(x=factor(iteration),y=bottles,colour=Team ,group=Team)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(16))
ggplot(observweak,aes(x=factor(iteration),y=bottles,colour=Team ,group=Team)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(16))
```

That is, three graphs displaying the same thing but for difference dataset each time. I want to compare between them, therefore I want their y axis to be fixed to the same scale with the same margins on all graphs, something the currently doesn't happen automatically.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a `facet_wrap` on all the observations, combined into a single dataframe, might be what you're looking for. E.g.

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

observ <- rbind(
  mutate(observbest, category = "best"),
  mutate(observmedium, category = "medium"),
  mutate(observweak, category = "weak")
)

qplot(iteration, bottles, data = observ, geom = "line") + facet_wrap(~category)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `+ ylim(min_value,max_value)` to each graph.

Another option would be to merge the three datasets with an id variable identifying which value is in which dataset, and then plot the three of them together, differentiating them by `linetype` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scale_y_continuous` to define the y axis for each graph and make them all easily comparable.