# How to set equal panel horizontal space when use scale = "free_y"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

```
set.seed(3)

data <- tibble(Group = c(rep("g1", 10), rep("g2", 10), rep("g3", 10)), 
    Value = c(runif(10, min = 1, max=5), runif(10, min = 1, max=5), runif(10, min = -5, max=5)))

ggplot(data, aes(Group, Value)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ Group, scales = "free")
```

You can see when y with decimal/negative values, the space become bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a [fixed width for your y-axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678561/786542)

```r
ggplot(data, aes(Group, Value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Group, scales = "free") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(label) sprintf("%10.1f", label))
```

[image]

Or flip the plot with `coor_flip()`

```r
ggplot(data, aes(Group, Value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(Group ~ ., scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121528/how-do-i-set-width-of-y-axis-labels-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks for you answer. [ps: monospaced font is needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678561/7198734)